# cv::imread returns NULL (XCode)

Tags: xcode, opencv

I'm trying to use cv::imread to load a picture using xcode 4.4 on mac os 10.8.
I have an absolute path to the picture called tp as shown below:

> ```
> NSString *testPic = [picturesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"0.bmp"];
> const char* tp = [testPic cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
> ```

I'm sure the path is correct since I can load the picture as UIImage from that path.

then I have the following code:

> cv::Mat src = cv::imread(tp);

and it returns NULL (src.data).

I've also tried:

> ```
> IplImage *tmp = cvLoadImage(tp);
> cv::Mat src(tmp);
> ```

but tmp is also NULL after the first line is executed.

any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that picturesDirectory contains the full absolute path containing the reference to the bundle in which the bmp is located?